# How can I redirect everything in one sub directory using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website and need everything in my subdomain to redirect to my home page.

For example I would need `www.website.com/sub` to redirect back to `www.website.com`

same with anything else within `/sub`

so `www.website.com/sub/sdjdj/sdsd/dsd ....`would also need to redirect to `www.website.com`

How can I achieve this with htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^sub(?:/|$) / [NC,R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in your .htaccess in the root.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sub(?:$|/.*) / [R=302,L]
```

When you are sure the rule is working as intended, change to `301` in rule.